# Show "status" in SWT JFace Eclipse - Composite

Tags: eclipse, swt, show, status, jface

I have a sash from component of a view which needs to be extended a little.

The view lists accounts.

The idea is to show a small notification on top of the component that a certain account is being viewed at the same time. The appropriate listeners and methods are ready but i got not GUI skills...

Could anybody help me out and suggest a way of doing this?

A small red sentence saying "account 1, 2 are currently viewed" should be displayed on top of the thing...

What to use? `CoolBar`? Status bar? and how is it used? I didn't find too good examples...

Answer (score 2):

You could use a SWT label to display that information. Here is a SWT snippet that shows you how to use it. This is where it's coming from: http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/. This should help you get started building GUIs with SWT and JFace.

```java
/*******************************************************************************
 * Copyright (c) 2000, 2010 IBM Corporation and others.
 * All rights reserved. This program and the accompanying materials
 * are made available under the terms of the Eclipse Public License v1.0
 * which accompanies this distribution, and is available at
 * http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html
 *
 * Contributors:
 *     IBM Corporation - initial API and implementation
 *******************************************************************************/
package org.eclipse.swt.snippets;

/*
 * GridLayout snippet: show a wrappable Label that fills available width
 * without expanding it
 * 
 * For a list of all SWT example snippets see
 * http://www.eclipse.org/swt/snippets/
 */
import org.eclipse.swt.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class Snippet335 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Display display = new Display();
    Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

    Label label = new Label(shell, SWT.WRAP | SWT.BORDER);
    GridData labelData = new GridData();
    labelData.widthHint = 10;                    /* default width */
    labelData.horizontalAlignment = SWT.FILL;    /* grow to fill available width */
    label.setLayoutData(labelData);
    label.setText("Snippets are minimal stand-alone programs that demonstrate specific techniques or functionality.");
    new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH).setText("This button determines the Shell's width");

    /* do an initial pack() so that the Shell determines its required width */
    shell.pack();

    /* update the Label's width hint to match what the layout allocated for it */
    labelData.widthHint = label.getBounds().width;

    /*
     * do a second pack() so that the Label will compute its required height
     * based on its correct width instead of its previously-set default width
     */
    shell.pack();

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) display.sleep();
    }
    display.dispose();
}

}
```